# Talend: Converting a string to BigDecimal

Tags: talend

I am trying to convert a string number from one MySQL table to another.

I have used the following on many occasions, however it does not seem to be working in this instance and I am unsure as to why. The string it is converting is `50,000.00`.

[image: Formula generating error]

With that formula in tMap it produces the following error:

[image: Error]

When I look at the code on 3031:

[image: code being used]

So something is just not functioning as I expect. Any help would be great.

Comment: Could you put text information like errors and code into Stack Overflow directly, rather than pasting in images? It helps to be able to refer to them directly.

Answer (score 1):

In regex syntax, "$" indicates the end of the string. In your regex, you are trying to remove any character after the end of the string which is not a number or a dot, which won't work, so the "," is never removed from your string, resulting in a conversion error.
You can do this:

```
new BigDecimal(row1.Trade_Amount.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""))
```